# Javascript library (tabSlideOut) hosted on GoogleCode returning 403 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-403, google-code, tabslideout

One of the Javascript files we use in a website is reporting a 403 error when we try to request it from googlecode.com.

http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

This has previously been working without any problems for many months.

The problem is inconsistent in that it seems to work in my office but if I log on to an external machine it returns the 403. This may be down to caching so I'm not focusing too much on that.

Does anybody have any ideas how this might have happened? It's quite worrying that code hosted externally can suddenly be inaccessible!

Answer (score 0):

It seems working at my end as well.

You may track the URL requested using firebug.
or
Please provide the URL of webpage in which you are accessing JS file because sometimes cross site scripting is the reason.

Thanks,
Krishan

Comment: The url requested and response which I've put in my question were retrieved from FireBug. I don't think it's cross site scripting because if I search for "tabSlideOut" on code.google.com I get a 403 as well. https://code.google.com/p/tab-slide-out/source/browse/trunk/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.5.js?r=14

Answer (score 0):

Alan, I had to find another source for the .js file.  I downloaded it from the page below and referenced it from within my site. The file I found is under the Android section of code.google.com, but it appears to be working fine:

http://code.google.com/p/androidoc/downloads/detail?name=jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js&can=2&q=

- Vince